# Wifi network list empty after suspend

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

Thinkpad t60p
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
32-bit
Possible reason: Ubuntu was upgraded to 16.04 on another machine (that died), the HDD was moved over to the t60p

I've tried 
sudo service network-manager restart 
And
sudo systemctl retart network-manager.service

Also testet to flip physical switch in combination with the above.

I also did
sudo apt-get remove wicd

All steps suggested in another thread.

Comment: Download the .deb files of network-manager and network-manager-gnome from ubuntu's website. Then, uninstall both of them. Later, using `sudo dpkg -i` install install them back from where the two files were saved.( Warning: Don't type sudo apt autoremove after uninstalling ).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1585863). You can use this command:

> sudo iwlist scan

or

> sudo wpa_cli scan

to scan manually. This is a temporary solution. You either need scripts or other methods to fix the situation permanently.

Comment: You could put `iwlist scan` or `wpa_cli scan` (no need for `sudo`) into the Power Management scripts, see `man -k pm|egrep  '^pm-'`.  and `dpkg -L pm-utils`